# Eigenvectors of the convex combination of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

I have a $n \times n$ irreducible row-stochastic matrix $P$ for which I already know its *invariant distribution centrality* $\pi$, i.e.:
$$
\pi \in [0,1]^{n} : P^T \pi = \pi, \quad \sum_{i}^{n}\pi_i = 1
$$

I am struggling in relating $\pi$ with the leading eigenvector of $P^{\lambda}$, that is a $\Lambda$-convex combination of $P$ and the identity, i.e.:
$$
\pi^{\lambda} \in [0,1]^{n} : \big({P^{\lambda}}\big)^T \pi^\lambda = \pi^\lambda, \quad \sum_{i}^{n}\pi^\lambda_i = 1
$$

With $P^{\lambda} = \Lambda + (I - \Lambda)P$ and $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n)$ (with, of course, $\lambda_i \in [0,1] \ \forall i$).

I already know that when $\nexists i: \lambda_i = 1$ then, trivially,
$$
\pi^{\lambda} = (I-\Lambda)^{-1} \pi
$$
Since 1 is a geometrically and algebraically simple eigenvalue for irreducible matrices.
I am interest in the case in which there are some $\lambda$s such that $I-\Lambda$ is no longer invertible.

Would highly appreciate some help in this!